# Need to show events as dots in jquery e-calendar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am working on with `jquery e-calendar` and I need to show dots as an event on particular dates.
Condition is like need to **show maximum three dots**

- If there is one event need to show one dot.
- If there are two events need to show two dots.
- If there are three events need to show three dots.
- If there are four events need to show three dots.

Here is my code...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').eCalendar({
    weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    textArrows: {
      previous: '<',
      next: '>'
    },
    eventTitle: 'Events',
    url: '',
    // date formate year month date 
    // time formate HH:MM:SS
    events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        description: 'Description 1',
        datetime: new Date()
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 2',
        description: 'Description 2',
        datetime: new Date("2020-03-25 04:00:00")
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 3',
        description: 'Description 3',
        datetime: new Date("2020-01-25 05:00:00")
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 4',
        description: 'Description 4',
        datetime: new Date("2020-01-25 06:00:00")
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 5',
        description: 'Description 5',
        datetime: new Date("2020-01-25 07:00:00")
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 6',
        description: 'Description 6',
        datetime: new Date("2020-01-25 08:00:00")
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 7',
        description: 'Description 7',
        datetime: new Date("2020-01-25 09:00:00")
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar/js/jquery.e-calendar.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar/css/jquery.e-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Please suggest me or help me to achieve this functionality

Comment: where u want to show the dot ?

Comment: I want to show dots at the bottom of the particular date

Comment: In this case, you got 6 events on 25/01 right? should show six dots?

Comment: No, I need to show a maximum three dots.